# How to write merge function for mergeSort in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm learning C++ and trying to write the merge function that will take two sorted lists and combine them into one sorted list. This should run in O(n) time. Below is my code:

```
LinkedList<T> LinkedList<T>::merge(const LinkedList<T>& other) const {

  LinkedList<T> left = *this;
  LinkedList<T> right = other;

  LinkedList<T> merged;

  if (left.size() <= 1) {
    return left;
  }
  else{
    while (left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0){

          if (left.front() <= right.front()){
            merged.pushBack(left.front());
            left.popFront();
          }
          else {
            merged.pushBack(right.front());
            right.popFront();
          }
      }
  }

  return merged;
}
```

This is my test:

```
Testing merge():
Left List: [(1)(3)(5)]  Right List: [(-1)(2)(10)(20)]
Merged: [(-1)(1)(2)(3)(5)]
Expected: [(-1)(1)(2)(3)(5)(10)(20)]
```

I think this is happening because when one of the lists become empty, the loop stops. Can anyone suggest me on how to deal with this? Many thanks.

Comment: Also it would be better if you provided an iterator for your list to make possible code like `for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) { ... }`. Right now you need to destroy the whole list just to iterate over its elements, which looks more like a queue. When something has the name `LinkedList`, it's natural to assume you can at least read its contents without destroying it.

Comment: I don't quite follow -> you mean popping the list elements are not encouraged?

Comment: Nothing wrong with popping in general, but consider this: even in your example, in order to traverse the list, you need to *make a copy of it* and then destroy it by popping all of the elements. This means that, even if you only wanted to look at the second element (without modifying the list), you would first need to copy *all* of the elements, which is very inefficient.

Comment: also this wouldn't work at all for lists of non-copyable types

Comment: You might consider implementing the equivalent of [std::list::splice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice), to move nodes within a list or from one list to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the main while loop where it has the condition to run until both arrays contain elements. So when one of them is empty it exits and one of the arrays might still contain the left-over elements. You need to add a while loop outside also to go thru remaining elements add to the result array. Here is the sample:

```
while (left.size() > 0)
{
            merged.pushBack(left.front());
            left.popFront();
}
while (right.size() > 0)
{
            merged.pushBack(right.front());
            right.popFront();
}
```